# How to build a secure connection between Web-Portal and Salesforce

Tags: portal

Customer has a web portal on its corporate web server. Users of the web portal should be able to update their personal information which is stored on a user record in SF, directly from portal in secure manner.

Communication between salesforce and web portal should be secure. Which two option describe the solution -

-Configure trusted IP ranges in salesforce for customer.
-Configure salesforce as identity provider.
-Configure two way SSL communication between the portal and salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

1. Create a afdc community and allow the users to register and update the records (maybe it will be necessary to build some kind of SSO infra to allow the users to sign in with the same credentials in the web portal and the SFDC portal)
2. Create a new technical user. User the language of the web portal org to write a connector between the external portal and salesforce. You can use REST services to connect the external portal and salesforce.

Answer (score 0):

In support of exposing this functionality using core SFDC functionality, I've implemented this with the [PHP toolkit](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/PHP_Toolkit).

In this stack, your web portal is written in HTML, it uses ASYNC ajax to call your PHP functions on your web server that call the PHP SOAP library that integrates with Salesforce via API.  Objects are returned as POPOs (Plain Old PHP Objects) and INSERT/UPDATE keywords work, too, just like DML.

Use an integration account to silo the credentials that will allow this functionality to operate indefinitely.  I recommend bolting your PHP code onto an existing CMS running on a stock web server (Wordpress, for example).  There are plenty of Membership plugins and whatnot to expand user-experience from there.

If you're using Wordpress, google around 'NONCE' for enhanced ajax security in that web server stack.